# Firebase Storage Upload Error: FIRStorageErrorDomain Code=-13000

Tags: swift, firebase, storage

I am trying to upload an image to Firebase and I actually succeeded several times yesterday, but today I'm getting this error:

> Optional
>     - Some : Error Domain=FIRStorageErrorDomain Code=-13000 "An unknown error occurred, please check the server response." UserInfo={ResponseErrorDomain=FIRStorageErrorDomain, object=ProfileImages/ascascasc ascas.jpg, error_name=ERROR_USER_NOT_FOUND, bucket=ichallenge-c52ae.appspot.com, ResponseErrorCode=-13020, NSLocalizedDescription=An unknown error occurred, please check the server response.}

I want to reiterate: nothing was changed in the code between yesterday and today, it just stopped working. This is the code, I've highlighted the line where it happens with a comment:

```
@IBAction func signUpButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject)
{
    // If textfields have more than 3 characters
    if firstNameTextField.text!.characters.count > 3 && passwordTextField.text!.characters.count > 3 && emailTextField.text!.containsString("@")
    {
        createUser()

        //Goes to Main Storyboard
        parseOutdated.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock { (success: Bool, error: NSError?) in
            NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("Login", object: nil)

        }
    }
    else
    {
        firstNameShake.shakeAnimation()
        lastNameShake.shakeAnimation()
        passwordShake.shakeAnimation()
        emailShake.shakeAnimation()
    }
}

func createUser()
{
    //Unwrap optionals before pushing to Firebase Database
    let name: String = "\(self.firstNameTextField.text!) \(self.lastNameTextField.text!)"

    storeProfileImage(name)
}

func storeProfileImage(name: String)
{
    let profileImageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.profileImageView.image!, 1.0)

    // Create a reference to the file you want to upload
    let profileImageRef = storageRef.child("ProfileImages/\(name).jpg")

    // Upload the file to the path defined above
    profileImageRef.putData(profileImageData!, metadata: nil) { metadata, error in
        if (error != nil) //ERROR HAPPENS HERE
        {
            print("Image not stored: ", error?.localizedDescription)
        }
        else
        {
            //Stores the profile image URL and sends it to the next function
            let downloadURL = metadata!.downloadURL()
            self.storeUserData(name, profileImageURL: downloadURL!)
        }
    }
}
```

Here's a screenshot of the breakpoint in XCode:

[image: I don't understand why the Error says "ERROR_USER_NOT_FOUND", as I haven't tried to authenticate at all]

Any help provided would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: Did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have been testing with the same user witout signing out on your app, your authentication token might have expired. Try signing out firs